# Moving string elements into another string in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, emu8086

I am trying to move elemenet by element a string into another string in assembly language. The problem is I keep getting errors at assembly time like: "Can't add relative types". Why is this happening and how could I fix it so that I can copy all elements from STRING into STRING2?

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
STRING DB 1, 2, 3, 4 ; first string
LENGTH DB $-STRING ; length of the first string
ITERATOR DB 0
DATA ENDS
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC  'DATA'
STRING2 DB 100 DUP (?) ; second string
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
START PROC FAR
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
PUSH DS
XOR AX, AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV CL, LENGTH ; 
THELOOP:
MOV ITERATOR, CL
SUB ITERATOR, 1
MOV STRING2[ITERATOR], STRING[ITERATOR] ; this is where the error appears
LOOP THELOOP

RET
START ENDP
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression, `STRING[ITERATOR]` cannot be expressed in Intel Assembly.
You can only use one memory reference in an instruction; anything else would have to be a register.
Furthermore, you cannot move memory to memory directly, except using `movs`:

```
push ds
push es
mov ax, DATA
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

mov si, offset STRING
mov di, offset STRING2
xor ch, ch
mov cl, [LENGTH]
rep movsb          ; movsb: move a byte from ds:si to es:di, and increment si and di

pop es
pop ds
```

Alternatively, closer to your solution, you'll have to load a memory value into a register, and then store it:

```
  xor bx, bx
  xor ch, ch    # the loop instruction uses all of cx!
THELOOP:
  mov al, STRING[bx]
  mov STRING2[bx], al
  inc bx
  loop THELOOP
```